# How to store javascript values into mysql database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm trying to store the users BMI score and comments into mysql database. I'm able to store their height and weight but just not their score and bmi comment.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Calculate()
    {
        //Obtain user inputs
        var height=Number(document.getElementById("height").value);
        var heightunits=document.getElementById("heightunits").value;
        var weight=Number(document.getElementById("weight").value);
        var weightunits=document.getElementById("weightunits").value;


       //Convert all units to metric
       if (heightunits=="inches") height/=39.3700787;
       if (weightunits=="lb") weight/=2.20462;
       if (heightunits=="cm") height/=100;

      //Perform calculation
      var BMI=weight/Math.pow(height,2);

      //Display result of calculation
      document.getElementById("output").innerText=Math.round(BMI*100)/100;

      var output =  Math.round(BMI*100)/100
       if (output<18.5)
       document.getElementById("comment").innerText = "Underweight";
       else   if (output>=18.5 && output<=25)
       document.getElementById("comment").innerText = "Normal";
       else   if (output>=25 && output<=30)
       document.getElementById("comment").innerText = "Obese";
       else   if (output>30)
       document.getElementById("comment").innerText = "Overweight";
      // document.getElementById("answer").value = output; 
    }
</script>
 </head>
 <body>

<div>BMI Calculator</div>

<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="Calculate(this.form);">
<input type="submit" name="savebmi" value="SaveBMI">

<p class="font-3">Your BMI is: <span name="output" value="output" type="float"     id="output" class="textInput"></span></p>

<p class="font-3">This means you are: <span name="comment" type="text"     id="comment"></span> </p>
```

Comment: you need to save the bmi to a hidden form field, or just re-compute it on the backend

Comment: thanks for answering! Do you know how I would go about with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is change your `span` tags to `input` tags and then just change your JavaScript to set the `value` attribute instead of the `innerText`.  Then when you submit the form, it will pass those values to your PHP script.

You can always style your input boxes to match your paragraph text if don't like the appearance of boxes.  For example, start with `style='border:none`.

JavaScript

```
  //Display result of calculation
  document.getElementById("output").value=Math.round(BMI*100)/100;

  var output =  Math.round(BMI*100)/100
   if (output<18.5)
   document.getElementById("comment").value = "Underweight";
   else   if (output>=18.5 && output<=25)
   document.getElementById("comment").value = "Normal";
   else   if (output>=25 && output<=30)
   document.getElementById("comment").value = "Obese";
   else   if (output>30)
   document.getElementById("comment").value = "Overweight";
  // document.getElementById("answer").value = output;
```

HTML

```
<p class="font-3">Your BMI is: <input name="output" type="float" id="output" class="textInput" style="border:none" /></p>

<p class="font-3">This means you are: <input name="comment" type="text" id="comment" style="border:none" /></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements with id *output* and *comment* are not `input` elements but `span`, so they are not passed to the PHP script.
You should try to pass this via AJAX to your script, then you can add these values to the request.
Example:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        // Whatever you want to do with the php response
    }
}
req.open("POST", "script.php", true);
req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
req.send("output=" + output + "&weight=" + weight + ...);
```

Another workaround is to use hidden `input` elements, but then you should make a function to validate these or make it non-editable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to fit your question..

```
//Display result of calculation
var bmi_result = Math.round(BMI*100)/100;

document.getElementById("output").innerText=bmi_result;
document.getElementById("form_output").innerText=bmi_result;

var comment = '';
if (bmi_result<18.5) {
   comment  = "Underweight";
} else   if (bmi_result>=18.5 && output<=25) {
   comment  = "Normal";
} else   if (bmi_result>=25 && output<=30) {
   comment  = "Obese";
} else   if (bmi_result>30) {
   comment  = "Overweight";
}

document.getElementById("comment").innerText = comment;
document.getElementById("form_comment").innerText = comment;
```

In your form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="form_output" name="output" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="form_comment" name="comment" value="">
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="Calculate(this.form);">
```